# How does java if statement handle null values?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have stumbled upon this odd behaviour while working with jasper soft reports and I would like to have it explained since I don't know much about Java.

Basically, I have a print when expression:

```
($P{Parameter_name}!=0 || $P{Parameter_name}==null)
? true : false
```

-> this returns false

```
($P{Parameter_name}==null || $P{Parameter_name}!=0)
? true : false
```

-> this returns true

The only difference is the equation order but logically it shouldn't make a difference.
The parameter is `null`.

I know that for example SQL wouldn't care for the order and would always evaluate true with a simple or statement like this.

Comment: That is not Java code, so why would you care what Java does?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` when evalulating

```
$P{Parameter_name}!=0
```

And maybe this exception will prevent Jasper from checking the second condition.

In your second version, the test

```
$P{Parameter_name} == null
```

will be evaluated to true, which means that

```
$P{Parameter_name} != 0
```

won't be evaluated at all (and no NPE will be raised)

Comment: Except that Jasper doesnt return any error to me but rather sees it as a false value, which i dont understand.